# Value of if-statement always null?

Tags: java, string, methods, substring

I'm trying to write a method in java to run cases of a user-entered string.

The code:

```
 static String checkWMI(String userVIN){

    String manCountry = null;
    String WMI = userVIN.substring(0, 5);
    String Wcheck = WMI.substring(WMI.length()- 4);

    if(Wcheck.equals("1") || Wcheck.equals("4") || Wcheck.equals("5")) {
         manCountry = "United States";
    }else if(Wcheck.equals("J")){
        manCountry = "Japan";
    }else if(Wcheck.equals("2")){
        manCountry = "Canada";
    }else if(Wcheck.equals("3")){
        manCountry = "Mexico";
    }else if(Wcheck.equals("S")){
        manCountry = "United Kingdom";
    }else if(Wcheck.equals("W")) {
        manCountry = "Germany";
    }

    return manCountry;
}
 }
```

The goal is to get a specific sub-string (so I can print it out later) and then determine a value based on a piece of that substring. I want to decide this based on the character indexed at zero. When I try to run this code, only "null" prints because it says my "if statement is always false". I know there must be a logic error somewhere, but I can't find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the input string(userVIN) you provided? I suspect it is going to else case which is not defined here.

Comment: @Sai A string of 17 characters: digits or letters. So something like "W1234567890123456".

Comment: Hint: try printing out the value of `Wcheck`. I don't think its what you expect it to be. (I'd also strongly advise you to start following normal Java naming conventions - and if you only want a single character, I'd use `charAt` rather than getting a string...)

Comment: I don't think the substring method that takes a single parameter does what you think it does. I recommend reading its documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int) - So `WMI.substring(WMI.length()- 4);` on a WMI with length 5 will return a substring of length 4. And why a String with a length of 4 is not equal to any of the Strings with length 1 you check in your if statements should be obvious.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yep, WMI is actually "2345", rather than "W", like I was hoping.

Comment: Btw. if all you want to check is what letter the String starts with there already is a String method called `startsWith` - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String) - exactly for that. That's why reading the official documentation is considered important. Because it tells you what methods are available and what they actually do which will lead to much better results than just guessing.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Oh wow. Yeah, I didn't know that...
Sorry about that everyone; this problem suddenly seems very trivial.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, wouldn't repeated checking for `startsWith` impact performance in tight loops? I kind of think that obtaining a character first and then checking it against a dictionary will degrade a lot less performance-wise with growing number of countries.

Comment: Though, seeing what the [WMI is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number#World_manufacturer_identifier), it's kind of not suitable to a simple dictionary check, because first letter doesn't necessarily denote the country, you also need a second letter that's checked against a range of options in general case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

static String checkWMI(String userVIN){

```
String manCountry = null;
String WMI = userVIN.substring(0, 5);

if(WMI.startsWith("1") || WMI.startsWith("4")  || WMI.startsWith("5") ) {
     manCountry = "United States";
}else if(Wcheck.equals("J")){
    manCountry = "Japan";
}else if(Wcheck.equals("2")){
    manCountry = "Canada";
}else if(Wcheck.equals("3")){
    manCountry = "Mexico";
}else if(Wcheck.equals("S")){
    manCountry = "United Kingdom";
}else if(Wcheck.equals("W")) {
    manCountry = "Germany";
}

return manCountry;
```

}
}

or

```
static String checkWMI(String userVIN){

String manCountry = null;
String WMI = userVIN.substring(0, 5);

if(WMI.charAt(0) == "1" || WMI.charAt(0) == "4"  || WMI.charAt(0) == "5"  ) {
     manCountry = "United States";
}else if(Wcheck.equals("J")){
    manCountry = "Japan";
}else if(Wcheck.equals("2")){
    manCountry = "Canada";
}else if(Wcheck.equals("3")){
    manCountry = "Mexico";
}else if(Wcheck.equals("S")){
    manCountry = "United Kingdom";
}else if(Wcheck.equals("W")) {
    manCountry = "Germany";
}

return manCountry;
```

}
}